# How to reorder an array by NSDates and NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I have an array that contains a custom class of mine called 'Game'. Each 'Game' contains an NSDate. I would like to reorder my Array based on the dates so that they are in order from newest to oldest. How could I do that? Also, my class 'Game' contains an NSString. How could I reorder my Array so that the games are alphabetized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a *REALLY* simple way to do this, and that's with an [`NSSortDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSArray *games = ...; //your unsorted array of Game objects
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDateDescending = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDateDescending];

NSArray *sortedGames = [games sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Apple's already written the sorting code.  It just needs to know what properties to sort *by*.  That's what an `NSSortDescriptor` encapsulates.  Once you've got one, simply give it to the array, and the array give you back a sorted version.  (Alternatively, if you have an `NSMutableArray`, you can sort it in-place using `-sortUsingDescriptors:`)

Answer (score 2):

The array must be an NSMutableArray object before you can re-order it, correct me if I am wrong.

In order to sort the array you need to write a custom sort method in the Game class. Something like:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareGameByString:(Game *)otherGame
{ return [[self stringValue] caseInsensitiveCompare:[otherGame stringValue]]; }
```

Then:

```
[yourMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareGameByString:)];
```

Comparing dates:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByDate:(Game *)otherGame
{
   if( [otherGame isKindOfClass:[Game class]] )
   {
      // NSdate has a convenient compare method
      return [[self dateValue] compare:[otherGame dateValue]];
   }
```

Also note that in the event of your array containing an object that does not respond to these selectors, thus an object that is not a Game object that you will get an exception, and that your app might break

Comment: You can sort a regular array using `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]`.  Or you can use an `NSSortDescriptor` and not have to worry about writing the comparison code.